# В чем проблема с моим JUnit тестом?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

У меня есть такой тест:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ColumnsTypesProcessorTest {

@Mock
private List<RowStatisticProcessor> rowProcessorList;
@Mock
private List<CellStatisticProcessor> cellProcessorList;

@InjectMocks
private MetaDataComputer metaDataComputer = new MetaDataComputer();

private MetaDataReader metaDataReader;
private String file;
private String outputFile;

@Before
public void init() {
    this.metaDataReader = new MetaDataReader();
}

@Test
public void integerType__shouldOk() throws IOException {
    this.file = "src/test/resources/integer-test.csv";
    this.outputFile = "src/test/resources/output-integer-test.json";

    when(metaDataComputer.inferMetadataForDataFrame(file)).thenReturn(setMetadata(outputFile));
}
```

Но он кидает NPE из-за того, что rowProcessorList и cellProcessorList не мокаются, в чем проблема?

Comment: 1. исходя из вышеприведенного кода списки вообще не нужны 2. зачем их вообще мокать ?!

Comment: @keekkenen вы правы, мокито не умеет мокать листы. Их нужно замокать, так как в классе есть эти листы, проблему решил замокав сами объекты листов и в конструкторе добавил их в лист.

Comment: непонятно, зачем нужны листы ?

Comment: @keekkenen потому листы есть в реализации класса, который нужно протестировать.

Comment: лучше приведите код метода, который тестируется

Comment: @keekkenen не понимаю, для чего? Класс, который InjectMock содержит поля, которые mock. И эти поля - это листы.

Comment: чтобы понять в чем проблема с тестом, можно написать такой код, который нельзя протестировать

Comment: @keekkenen но здесь, очевидно, какой-то баг, так как падает NPE.

Comment: телепатия не мой профиль

Comment: @keekkenen но в вопросе написано, что падает NPE, не вижу проблемы, но спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мокито не умеет мокать листы. Чтобы решить проблему, замокал объекты типа листов и добавил их в лист в конструкторе.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо в методе @Before инициализировать моем

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

Comment: Так я тоже пробовал, и все равно NPE.

Comment: Это может быть связано с версией? У меня 3.2.4.

Comment: Я вот нет уверен точно что насчёт Java. Но в котлине мокито не мокает списки. Обычно мокается единичный элемент, и список уже создаётся руками из моков. Попробуйте такой вариант

Comment: Извините, а вы не подскажите как это делается?

Comment: Ну вы просто создаёте такой же мок как сейчас, только убирайте List. А потом уже создаёте реальный объект списка и методом add добавляете несколько моков, я так думаю раз вы пытаетесь замокать весь список то можете добавить один объект несколько раз, а если вам не важен размер списка то вообще просто создаёте список из одного элемента.

Comment: ArrayList list = new ArrayList ();.   list.add(mock)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107234/discussion-between-kaylil-01-and--).